# Не очень понимаю как написать правильно код для задания. Помогите

Tags: vba

Дан одномерный массив А размерности N. В нем есть нулевые элементы.  Создать массив В из номеров этих элементов.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myar() As Integer
Dim n As Integer, s As Integer
n = Val(TextBox1)
ReDim myar(1 To n)
For i = 1 To n
    myar(i) = Int(Rnd() * n)
    ListBox1.AddItem myar(i)
Next i

s = WorksheetFunction.match(0, myar)
MsgBox s
MsgBox myar(s)

End Sub
```

Comment: Чтобы вопрос не попал под удаление, уточните свою проблему - что именно "не очень понимаю"

Comment: Вы бы почитали хоть, что именно делает `WorksheetFunction.Match`, что ли...она делает поиск и возвращает позицию только одного, самого первого, элемента. А вовсе даже не массив со всеми позициями. Да и собственно массива для приёма результата в программе - тупо нету.